# Averaging multiple images from directory using numpy and PIL

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I've been trying to make an average image of multiple images. Each set of images is in it's own directory but I've just been placing them in the working directory with the python script. Each of these images is a 480x480 RGB .png image.

My biggest problem is that I'm using this code and getting the same error:

```
import os, numpy, PIL
from PIL import Image
# Access all PNG files in directory
allfiles=os.listdir(os.getcwd())
imlist=[filename for filename in allfiles if  filename[-4:] in [".png",".PNG"]]


# Assuming all images are the same size, get dimensions of first image
w,h=Image.open(imlist[0]).size
N=len(imlist)

# Create a numpy array of floats to store the average (assume RGB images)
arr=numpy.zeros((h,w, 3),numpy.float)

#print(arr)

# Build up average pixel intensities, casting each image as an array of floats
for im in imlist:
    imarr=numpy.array(Image.open(im),dtype=numpy.float)
    print(imarr)
    arr=arr+imarr/N

# Round values in array and cast as 8-bit integer
arr=numpy.array(numpy.round(arr),dtype=numpy.uint8)

# Generate, save and preview final image
out=Image.fromarray(arr,mode="RGB")
out.save("Average.png")
out.show()
```

Error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/storeys/Hardrive/Sam_Python/img.avg/img_avg.py", line 21, in <module>
    arr=arr+imarr/N
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (480,480,3) (480,480,4)
```

I'm not sure how to navigate this problem and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems one of your PNGs has an alpha channel, i.e. 4 instead of the conventional 3 RGB channels. You could neglect it for example via

```
imarr=numpy.array(Image.open(im),dtype=numpy.float)[:,:,:3]
```

Naturally, your code still assumes that all images in your list have the same height and width.